# How to keep only temporary data in DynamoDB with AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I am constantly writing data to a DynamoDB table. I would like the data to be stored in S3 as parquet files. In order to do this, I can use AWS Glue crawler.

The problem is, I dont want the DynamoDB table to grow everyday. I just want crawled data to be deleted from the table.

What is the best way to get the temporary data in DynamoDB, consolidate into single parquet file and put it into S3?